# Can I use volatile sig_atomic_t to avoid a mutex in C++03?

Tags: c++, mutex, volatile, stdatomic, sig-atomic-t

If I'm on hardware with atomic read and increment/decrement support, can I use a `volatile sig_atomic_t` in C++03 to get access to the atomic operations and avoid a full blown mutex or must I wait for C++11 and `std::atomic<int>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Some* compilers provide non-standard semantics for `volatile` which would allow that to work, but it's not portable.  `volatile` is for accessing hardware, **not** for inter-thread communication.  There is no guarantee that a write to a `volatile` variable by one thread will ever become visible to another thread -- for communication between threads you need synchronising operations such as memory barriers, which are provided by operations on `std::atomic` types.

For more info see ["volatile vs. volatile"](http://herbsutter.com/2009/01/12/effective-concurrency-volatile-vs-volatile/) and Hans Boehm’s ISO C++ paper ["Should volatile Acquire Atomicity and Thread Visibility Semantics?"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2016.html) (both links taken from the footnote to a recent [Herb Sutter blog post](http://herbsutter.com/2012/08/31/reader-qa-how-to-write-a-cas-loop-using-stdatomics/))

You don't have to wait for C++11 support in your compiler though, most platforms provide some platform-specific atomic operations that also include any necessary memory barriers, e.g. GCC's [`__sync`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) built-in, Solaris' atomic operations, or Win32's Interlocked functions.  There are also portable libraries such as the proposed [Boost.Atomic](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/) which provide a common interface to platform-specific implementations.